# Multiprocesses Ruby and store variables

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I would like to know how to multithread in ruby and store the results of the child processes in an array of the parent.

The array that I would like to process has 400 items.

I have tried 2 solutions.

```
Solution: 1 (http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/parallel-forkmanager/Parallel/ForkManager)

require forkmanager

eng = []

array = [{'ip' => 12.34.56,'hostname' => ''}, {'ip' => 22.22.22, 'hostname' => ''}

pm = Parallel::ForkManager.new(20)
pm.run_on_finish{|pid, exit_code, return_list|
  eng << return_list
}

array.each do |node|
  pm.start(node) and wait
  new_node = process(node) #gives a value to hostname 
  pm.finish(0, new_node)
end
pm.wait_all_children
puts eng #expects it to return new node but it returns node. 




Solution 2: (https://github.com/grosser/parallel)
require 'parallel'
eng =[]
array = [{'ip' => 12.34.56,'hostname' => ''}, {'ip' => 22.22.22, 'hostname' => ''}
Parallel.map(array, in_processes: 20) do |node|
  new_node = process(node) #gives a value to hostname 
  eng << new_node
end
puts eng #expected to provide nodes. returns empty array instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parallel.map` works much like `Enumerable.map` in that it returns the results of running each block on the given element in the array, and so you can simply do something like this to get the results of processing each node:

```
eng = Parallel.map(array, in_processes: 20) do |node|
  process(node) # Return the result of processing `node`. `Parallel.map` will return these results for each node in an array
end

puts eng # This will have the expected nodes now
```